# About radical of $(I,x)$ with $x$ irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $I$ be a proper ideal of a polynomial ring $A$ and $x \in A$  an irreducible element.

In a theorem of commutative algebra I will use the fact that, in this hypothesis, holds the following equality: $$\sqrt{(I,x^k)}=\sqrt{(\sqrt{I},x)}$$

The assert seems to be true, anyone has any counterexample/proof?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

more generally: $\sqrt{\sqrt I+ \sqrt J}=\sqrt{I+J}.$

Answer (score 0):

If you are working over an algebraically closed field, the assertion follows from the Nullstellensatz, since $V(I,f^k)=V(\sqrt{I},f)$ holds obviously.

edit: Ok, it is true in a even more general setting. For every commutative unitary ring the radicals of $(I,J)$ and $(\sqrt I,\sqrt J)$ coincide.